# Internet Explorer set cross domain cookies for authorization

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, cross-domain

I have two application on next domains: *www.bar.com* and *www.foo.bar.com*. Second application makes authorization via first application (using cross domain request)
After this I sets cookies to browser, and in the Internet Explorer it doesn't work:

```
$.cookie("SESSION_KEY", loginResult.sessionKey, {
        expires: 365,
        path: "/",
        domain: ".bar.com"
});
```

The code works in all browsers excepti Internet Explorer v.9 The cookie doen't set. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

This is due to IE settings.  From the `Tools` menu, select `Internet Options`.  Navigate to `Security` tab.  Select Internet web content zone and click `Custom Level` to open the Security Settings.

Locate `Miscellaneous` settings.  Try enabling `Access data sources across domains`.  You might need to restart IE for the settings to take effect.

Comment: But, it's a web application. I can't tell all users to do this in their browser. :)

Answer (score 2):

IE, as only one web browser in the market,  implements partialy P3P standart (which is about acceptance cookies in CORS)

So you can set cookies using server response - to do this you must set this header in server response (which set cookies) (I copy-paste below line from my PHP symfony project) :

```
$response->headers->set('P3P', 'CP="random_text"');
```

You must also remember about add flag 'withCredentials=true' to your CORS request (in other case, any cookies will be send/save from request/response).