# Google Apps Script Html Service and Internet Explorer error "This content cannot be displayed in a frame"

Tags: google-apps-script

I am finally getting my Google script to work. It works fine in Chrome. I am using htmlservice.createHtmlOutputFromFile and the site is obviously hosted on google sites.

But when I try the page in IE, I get

```
This content cannot be displayed in a frame    
To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher     of      this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.
```

I tried adding in head tag

```
meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="allow"
```

but it made no difference.
Is there a javascript trick or a GAS library function I can use to try to get  this to work cross browser?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is related to cross domain cookies.
Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764850/internet-explorer-set-cross-domain-cookies-for-authorization) maybe will work to you.